# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SHInitExtraControls referenced?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, smart-device

How can i resolve this error:

Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SHInitExtraControls referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl CTestApp::InitInstance(void)" (?InitInstance@CTestApp@@UAAHXZ) Test.obj

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link against `aygshell.lib`. Note that the [MSDN page for `SHInitExtraControls()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee505073.aspx) says that `aygshell.lib` is the required library to use it.

A [LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(VS.80).aspx) usually means that you forgot to provide a definition of something. In this case, the definition of `SHInitExtraControls()` is located in `aygshell.lib`. Without it, the linker will complain when you attempt to use `SHInitExtraControls()`.

To link against `aygshell.lib` in Visual Studio, go to `Project --> Properties --> Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies` then type `aygshell.lib` in the box.

Comment: Yes, you must link against `aygshell.lib` to use  the `SHInitExtraControls()` function.

Comment: Super helpful answer, simple and to the point. One thing to add - you can specify the full path in the include. I tried just including the file name, but ended up having to specify full path:

```
C:\Program Files\Agilent\B1530A\Lib_x64\wgfmu.lib
```